# kafka Java API Consumer and producer Offset value comparison?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a requirement to match Kafka producer offset value to  consumer offset by using Java API?

I am new to KAFKA,Could anyone suggest how to proceed with this ?

Comment: I would like to verify what is sent to kafka and what is received to kafka?

Comment: Could you please clarify the use case and why the need for matching offsets on producer and consumer side?

Comment: Hi @vahid my use case is to make sure that both producer and consumer offset are equal so that making sure that what is sent to kafka and received by kafka ?

Comment: Messages by Kafka Producer persist on disk for a configurable amount of time; and the Kafka Consumer will read them in the order they are stored. You can go with at-least-once, or at-most-once delivery in your application code; or you can go with the latest exactly-once message delivery. It is perfectly normal for consumer offset not be in sync with the latest partition offset, but as long consumer keep a steady pace it's considered a healthy eco-system.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact use case there are a couple of ways that you could go about this, but all of them will require an external system.

First of, Confluent offers the [Confluent Control Center](https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/docs/index.html) as part of their commercial offering, this would probably be the easiest way to go about this, if you are willing to spend the money.

If that is not for you, then you'd need to implement some sort of system to keep track of what you are producing and what you are consuming. For example you could simply use a database, take topic, partition and offset as primary key and have columns for produced_at and consumed_at. 
Every time your producer writes a message to the cluster you have it update the produced_at column (look at [ProducerInterceptor](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerInterceptor.html)). Same on the consumer side, you could implement an interceptor that confirms having read the message, or confirm from the consumer itself, once it has successfully been processed.

Or if you don't need every message confirmed you could just implement regular checkpointing every 10k messages or something similar and trust that the consumer read everything up to the last offset it confirmed.

There's also the possibility of injecting checkpoint messages into the stream at regular intervalls and when the consumer sees one of these it triggers an action - again, you have to trust the consumer that it got everything in between the checkpoints.

As I said initially, it all depends on your exact use case, if you give us more detail I'm sure we can come up with something that works for you.

**Update:**

If you want to retrieve the offset after sending a message to Kafka you need to check the Future that the producer returns on send, this will contain the offset.

```
      // Send message and  store the future
      Future<RecordMetadata> messageFuture = producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, byte[]>(topic,  serialize(currentMessage)));

      producer.flush();
      // as flush blocks until all operations have been completed (regardless of success or failure) we can be sure
      // that our future is available at this point

      try {
        RecordMetadata metaData = messageFuture.get(); 
        System.out.println("Sent message with offset: " + metaData.offset());
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // do some error handling
      }
```

Comment: Thanks sonke for your quick response .I am able to read offset value from consumer and my question is :     When producer produce the stream how would we read the offset from producer since  producer offset handled by framework ...  Could you tell me how to handle this ?

Comment: I've added some code that should explain the concept.

Comment: @SönkeLiebau The `future.get` is a blocking call which awaits until the message pushed to the broker.  Is the `flush` operation required ?

Comment: @Kamal: you are right of course, in the snippet above the flush is not strictly speaking necessary. I extracted this from a method that loops over collected records, sends all of them and then flushes before looping over futures to call get. For simplicity's sake I removed the loops but overlooked that the flush is not necessary any more in that case.

Comment: Hi @SönkeLiebau ..I tried all of the above what you guys mentioned and My exact requirement is : when producer produce a message with offset we will be able to read that using Producer API and in consumer we are reading the same message offset in consumer using Consumer API but here is my question is :Is there anyway to read the Producer offset in the Consumer API ?

Comment: @SönkeLiebau I wastrying to read the offset but ending up with below :              Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:781) at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:635)                                                                      KafkaConsumerNew.main(KafkaConsumerNew.java:22) Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol.PLAINTEXTSASL

Comment: Looks like you are passing in a wrong value for "security.protocol" in your consumer config "PLAIN‌​TEXTSASL" is not a supported value and should probably be "SASL_PLAINTEXT".

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the offset of the producer and the consumer via Java Management Beans. There by you can do the comparison in realtime using the JConsole provided with the JDK.

Read about [Gauge](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/apidocs/com/codahale/metrics/Gauge.html) on how to expose the offset position of the producer and the consumer.